# symfony2 - weird rendering of embedded form (OneToOne relation)

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a class `Person` which has an instance of `Adress`, because they have a `OneToOne` relationship.
The class `Employee` `extends` from `Person`.
I have a Form (Type) class `EmployeeForm` for Employee, which creates the form for an Employee. 
In this form I add a new `AdressForm` (the embedded form).
I use a form_theme `formStyle.html.twig`.

The result is this:[image]

Here the code:

Person:

```
class Person 
{
  ... (all the other attributes)
   /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Adress")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="adress_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
    * @Assert\Type(type="integer")
    * @Assert\NotBlank()
    */
   protected $adress;
   ... (getter and setter)
}
```

Employee:

```
class Employee extends Person 
{...}
```

AdressForm:

```
class AdressForm extends AbstractType 
{
    // set the data class of the form
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'KuMiV\StoreBundle\Entity\Adress',
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder       
            ->add('street', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Straße'))
            ->add('number', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Hausnummer'))
            ->add('city', 'text', array(
                'label'  => 'Stadt'))           
            ->add('zipCode', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Postleitzahl')) 
            ->add('country', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Land')) 
            ->add('addInfo', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Zusatzinformationen', 'required' => false));
    }

    public function getName() 
    {
        return 'adress';
    }
}
```

EmployeeForm:

```
class EmployeeForm extends AbstractType
{
    // set the data class of the form
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'KuMiV\EmployeeBundle\Entity\Employee',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Titel', 'required' => false))
            ->add('firstName', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Vorname'))
            ->add('lastName', 'text', array(
                'label'  => 'Nachname'))           
            ->add('gender', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array('m' => 'männlich', 'f' => 'weiblich')))
            ->add('email', 'email', array(
                'label' => 'Titel', 'required' => false)) 
            ->add('phone1', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Telefon 1', 'required' => false)) 
            ->add('phone2', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Telefon 2', 'required' => false))
            ->add('mobile', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Mobil', 'required' => false))
            ->add('fax', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Fax', 'required' => false)) 
            ->add('birth', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Geburtsdatum', 'required' => false))
            ->add('addInfo', 'textarea', array(
                'label' => 'Zusatzinformationen', 'required' => false))
            ->add('adress', new AdressForm())   
            ->add('save', 'submit', array(
                'label' => 'Speichern', 'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-success')))
            ->getForm();
    }

    public function getName() 
    {
        return 'employee';
    }
}
```

formStyle.html.twig:

```
{# app/Resources/views/formStyle.html.twig #}
{% block form_row %}
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_label(form) }}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
            {{ form_widget(form, {'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control'}}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock form_row %}
```

{

newItem.html.twig:

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% form_theme form 'formStyle.html.twig' %}  
...  
{% block pageHeader %} 
    Neuen Mitarbeiter erstellen
{% endblock pageHeader %}

{% block content %}
    <h3 class="sub-header">Personenbezogene Angaben</h3>
    {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'role': 'form'}}) }}
        <div class="row">   
        </div>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
    <h3 class="sub-header">Adresse</h3>
{% endblock content %}
```

Why is the embedded form rendered like a form_row?
Is it possible to call the form elements of employee and adress extra (in one form)? Like `form.employee` and `form.adress`? To get the adress form under the headline "Adresse" (and maybe the submit button on the bottom?) without calling any form element extra .

Comment: Did you try calling `{{ form_widget(form.address) }}`? You might need to declare each `{{ form_row() }}` manually if you want `form.address` to show at the end or somewhere that isn't in the order of the fields declaration.

Comment: Dawn, didn't think about the form theme. You are right, it's because of my form theme in which I use the grid system of twbs...
Manually it works. But the problem is, that I have many forms (with many rows) with equal relations and I don't want to write them all manually. Do you know another way like split the adress embedded form into it's attributes or something like that?

Comment: There isn't any magic solution for your problem. In my opinion, you should create a new `FormType` that include the two forms separately. Once you render them they will be separated and you will probably be able to define a header and all. I am pretty sure it can work out but I can't provide code sample. Once you have the solution, please answer your question, I am very curious how it can work out.

Comment: Didn't really get it work with the new FormType. 
Because of the grid system I use there is no other solution than the one you said: calling every field manually. Sadly I can't split the address stuff using my form theme with grid system.
Write your first comment as answer, it's the right solution.